# Index Hive table using Solr

Tags: solr, hive, hbase

I’ve got currently a big table stored in Hbase. I thought it makes sense because its values are documents but now I’ve been making some test using hive 0.14 over bucketed orc files and the queries are really fast. I was thinking to migrate it to hive and index the values using Solr. Is that a good approach or it’s better to leave it in hbase?

Thanks.